qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory in alpine linux on M1
I am trying to run Docker container using this https://hub.docker.com/r/gotechnies/php-5.6-alpine/dockerfile Dockerfile. After container running install aws cli using below command.
$ curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install

throwing error :
/sandbox # ./aws/install
qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory
You can now run: /usr/local/bin/aws --version

I tried setting
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64    or
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t php5 --progress=plain --no-cache . or
docker run -d --name webserver5 --platform linux/amd64 -p 8888:80 -v /Users/avinda-blrm24/workspace:/sandbox php5 runnning like this but no use.
Machine details where I am running Docker desktop
OS : macOS Sonoma
Chip : Apple M3 Pro
Docker desktop version : 4.33.0 (160616)
Any help ?

You're using an x86_64 (Intel) binary.  Can you use an ARM-based binary instead?  You may be able to use the local package manager (apk for an Alpine image) to install tools as well.

which command ? I can't use latest alpine image due to dependency on PHP5 packages.

For ARM based binary getting this error /sandbox # ./aws/install ./aws/install: line 155: /sandbox/aws/dist/aws: not found You can now run: /usr/local/bin/aws --version

since its alpine image, add glibc and awscli like below and try
ARG GLIBC_VERSION=2.35-r0
ARG AWSCLI_VERSION=2.11.11

# install glibc compatibility for alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && apk add --no-cache --force-overwrite \
        glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
        glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
        glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 \
    && ln -sf /usr/glibc-compat/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
    && curl -sL https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-${AWSCLI_VERSION}.zip -o awscliv2.zip \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && aws/install \
    && rm -rf \
        awscliv2.zip \
        aws \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/aws_completer \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/data/ac.index \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/examples \
        glibc-*.apk \
    && find /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/botocore/data -name examples-1.json -delete \
    && apk --no-cache del \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

